# Change Date Event in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone prayer time application, and I want to calculate the prayer time when mobile changes date automatically or by user hand ...
I've looked a lot to find the date changed event for Windows Phone,
but I don't know how to handle this event

Comment: What would a date changed event do? You mean, an event that fires at midnight? (If so, there isn't an event like that.)

Comment: Check for Background Task examples on msdn

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you are trying to ask still this could help you. Save your date in a variable dt globally and call the checkfunction() where ever you need to check the date. The checkfunction will keep invoking the startfunction() which in turn will keep calling the checkfunction() at a interval of 100 milliseconds.

```
private bool DateChanged(DateTime date)
    {
        if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, date) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void startfunction()
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                checkfunction();
            });
        });
    }
    public void checkfunction()
    {
        if (DateChanged(dt))
        {
            //execute code
        }
        else
        {
            startfunction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Every 100 milliseconds? That would be a significant amount of unnecessary CPU utilization.